# How to make VisualStudio autoformat a whitespace after the negation unary operator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-indent, unary-operator, autoformatting

In VisualStudio, C# code, if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> I can format all the document according to the <kbd><kbd>Tools</kbd>|<kbd>Options</kbd></kbd> / <kbd><kbd>Text editor</kbd>|<kbd>C#</kbd>|<kbd>Formatting</kbd></kbd> settings.

I **could not find any option to format the unary operators** although there are options for the binary operators instead.

I would like this code:

```
if( !Input.GetMouseButtonDown( 0 ) && Input.touchCount <= 0 )
```

to be auto-formatted as this:

```
if( ! Input.GetMouseButtonDown( 0 ) && Input.touchCount <= 0 )
```

ie: adding a white space between the `!` and the expression it negates.

**Question:**

How can I tell Visual Studio to format like that? Am I missing any obvious option that my eyes insist to skip? Is there any Plugin out there to do this?

**Side note:**

I'd even want to keep `++i` and `i++` together instead of `++ i` and `i ++` so it would be ideal if I can specify for which unary operator I want the space and for which not.

(Currently using `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015`, version `14.0.23107.0 D14REL`)